# Do I go to hell for not believing in the Hadith at all?

Tags: hadith, jahannam

I don't think I can believe in even the most authentic Hadith out there, because they all seem to be made up or fabricated in one way or another.

Now my question is, that, If I reject and refuse to believe in all of them, do I end up in Hell? Please Explain.

Comment: A relevant questions and answers http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30537/what-is-the-ruling-regarding-hadith-rejecters/ and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24773/is-the-quran-complete-if-so-why-do-we-need-hadith

Comment: If you don't believe in hadith how can you pray? ... Are you following Mohammad (pbuh) or whom?

Comment: I think there's a distinction between someone who rejects hadith out of concern of authenticity and the one who rejects hadiths because he does not think the Sunnah constitutes part of the shariah. the second one is definitely a kafir while the status of the first one I don't think can be a kafir.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, hadiths are not fabricated. For example, Bukhari validated each hadith meticulously with a criteria at 6 different levels. Please research the net or reach a book on how the hadiths were validated.

We have to follow Sunnah of Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) as documented in Quran. Yes, you will probably be punished to some extend for not following hadith or Sunnah of the Prophet.

The 6 authentic books of Hadith are Bukhari, Muslim, Tirmidhi, Abu Daud, Ibn Majah and Nissai. The compilers of these works took great pain to sift forged Hadith from the authentic ones and established a very strict criteria for this purpose so that no one could cast doubts about authenticity. The touch stone for the reliability of each hadith is the Quran itself.

Comment: Yes?? and where is the answer to the asked question? Please consider reading [answer]!

Comment: I have answered, you have to read again and spoon feeding is unnecessary, you need to do you additional research in order to overcome the doubts. We have free will, but only Allah can guide oneself. If you already disbelieve, then only way to validate is to conduct research on how hadiths were validated then you have free will to believe. Search the net for the names I mentioned in my comments.

Comment: Here is line from Quran besides others: "Whosoever obeyeth Allah and His Messenger he verily hath gained a signal victory." (33:71)

Comment: Still not reading properly. Read my comment where wording is 'punished'. And punishment is of course in hell in the hereafter unless decides to forgive.

Comment: Well your statement still needs elaboration, we have to follow the sunna as it is documented in the Quran (where?). you will be punished (why? references for that?)...

Answer (score -1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

> It was narrated from Abu Hurairah that : The Prophet said "I do not
>   want to hear of anyone of you who, upon hearing a Hadith narrated from
>   me, says while reclining on his pillow: 'Recite Qur'an (to verify this
>   Hadith).' (Here the Propher SAW said) Any excellent word that is said,
>   it is I who have said it." [How can you reject what I have said?](Ibn
>   majah)

According to Fardh i'tiqadi (Fard belief) ,If Daleel is Qati (Proved from Quran and Mutawatir Hadith undoubtfully) then rejector of Fard I'tiqati would be Kafir(Disbeliever) and there is a consensus among all four school of thoughts that if issue is clear enough to all (like Prayers,Ruku,Sajdah) then he would be considered as  Kafir (Disbeliever) and if some other person doubt about Kufr of rejector of Fard belief he would be considered as Kafir too.

> And when there came to them a Book from Allah confirming that which
>   was with them - although before they used to pray for victory against
>   those who disbelieved - but [then] when there came to them that which
>   they recognized, they disbelieved in it; so the curse of Allah will be
>   upon the disbelievers.How wretched is that for which they sold
>   themselves - that they would disbelieve in what Allah has revealed
>   through [their] outrage that Allah would send down His favor upon whom
>   He wills from among His servants. So they returned having [earned]
>   wrath upon wrath. And for the disbelievers is a humiliating
>   punishment.(Quran 2:89-90)

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: "Any excellent word that is said, it is I who have said it"

Are you really sure that Prophet said that? As far as I know, he would never, ever say anything (like that) which implies boasting, pride, ego or a God like state in himself.

Could you please cite some references for that. Thanks

Comment: @newtoislam http://www.sunnah.com/urn/1250210 here is the reference, Yeah you are right he never did show pride himself but it is actually to show the importance of hadith as mentioned in Quranic verse " he does not speak from his own desire."JazakAllah

Comment: Quoting a hadith, when the questioner doubts that hadiths are even valid in the first place, doesn't seem to be particularly useful here. Quoting a *da'if* hadith, even less so.

Comment: And the Qur'an quote doesn't seem to have anything to do with the answer at all.

Comment: The Quranic verse in an answer added is to clarify the destiny of disbelievers and verse added in the comment is for further expalanation of that hadith as the questioner has asked for it well the question doesnt seem to me for implying hadith in first place or not rather indication as refusing it completely, There is a consensus among all scholars that Da'if hadith could be quoted when it comes to Fadhail and importance,see more here http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2015/11/11/is-acting-on-weak-hadiths-an-innovation/ JazakAllah

Comment: "scholars technically permit it" isn't even remotely the same thing as "is actually useful here"