# Am I legitimate muslim?

Tags: hadith, imaan

My question is straightforward; am I still a Muslim and part of ahl Sunnah   to believe those ahadiths which is fundamental to the faith like praying, fasting, Hajj, etc whic I accept and practice, but to have a *neutral* position regarding those ahadiths which are dumb, nonsense, unscientific, degrading even if they are considered *authentic,* like for example:

- You can drink Camel's urine (a hadith from bukhari)
- Women have less intellect because of their deficiency in faith like because they can't pray when they have mense (so what's the fault of women if God gave them that physiology)
- Eating pus of husband still can't fullfill the rights of husband
- Violence like it is allowed to kill children of pagan and etc
- Not praying one time intentionally has the punishment of 80000 thousand years in hell (are you serious?)
- Women who pluck their eyebrows will never enter jannah (so it means plucking is now equivalent to shirk, seriously not entering jannah for just plucking eyebrows and it's authentic too)
  and there are thousands of non sense ahadiths that one can't digest it.....

So having said those things above and still believe in ahadiths which are certain that Muhammad has said and there are a bunch of ahadiths which don't suit modern thinking and who knows if they are  fabricated obviously it's not the word of God?

So my question is it ok in terms of faith to believe in certain ahadiths about fundamentals but to be NEUTRAL or REJECT some of it even they are considered AUTHENTIC but doesn't fit logic science moral?

[image][image][image]

Comment: From this perspective the qur'an isn't scientific either. And some of your comments seem to be based on a wrong hadith interpretation and I doubt that all the given examples are considered as sahih ahadith. And finally what if Muhammad really said so or how do you know he didn't ?

Comment: I have red those about ahadiths a week ago and I don't have the references to but I am not  lying you can search the the keywords on Google u can find it and secondly I have never doubted the quran what I am concerned is getting salvation not really relying or maybe rejecting  the hadiths BUT except those ahadiths that are fundamental which it has not any fawlt and doubt and doesn't sound wierd

Comment: I think that [What is the ruling regarding hadith rejecters?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30537/what-is-the-ruling-regarding-hadith-rejecters), maybe [Believing in hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/44232/believing-in-hadith?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Do I go to hell for not believing in the hadith at all](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30982/do-i-go-to-hell-for-not-believing-in-the-hadith-at-all) cover this.

Comment: Here you go!! Now don't tell that they are not authentic

Comment: Posting pictures isn't helpful you'd better linked quotes and mark the text passages that disturb you, and you better ask for clarification in another post. And finally If a question has an answer on the site we mark it as duplicate and link to it this is stackexchange standard procedure. If you disagree you should show what you miss in these, answers so don't tell us what we should do or leave. I don't see anything really new in this question post. The fact that a hadith appears in a so called sahih book is not a proof by itself that is really the speech of Muhammed.

Comment: There are many sahih Hadith that are misunderstood and misinterpreted. But that doesn't mean they are non sense. You just need to find the right explanation of those Hadith one by one.  If you ask all this at once it will be difficult for people answer your questions.

Comment: Before writing stupid words about the Hadiths I suggest you to first go to the source of that Hadith and read it yourself. Rather than just seeing some random posts on social media and believing that.

Answer (score 1):

**In short and concisely to answer your question:** you are not allowed to reject a hadith which is Sahih, however, you might have a different interpretation of it (or neutral until you have a concise understanding of it) **in the fold** of Islam. For example, hadiths for slavery does not apply anymore since it was abolished, the same applies to the hadiths that were said during wartime. So, looking at the context is important to avoid misunderstanding.

Also to mention, when it comes to accepting a hadith, you cannot just accept a hadith which has a very weak chain of narrations even if it makes sense to you unless it can be backed by Quran or other Sahih hadiths or does not contradict the fundamentals of the faith.

For example, there is no clear mention of dinosaur's existence mentioned in the Quran or Hadiths but one may find some indirect mentions of creatures that were destroyed before mankind and jinns. However, believing or not believing in dinosaurs does not really affect your faith directly or indirectly since it is not related to the fundamentals of faith or worship of one true God. Similarly, believing in aliens does not affect your deen since there is an implicit mention of it in the Quran. On the other hand, some scientific academics might try to show you empirical evidence of Human Evolution, no matter how strong the scientific argument is, since it contradicts the Islamic belief, it would not be permissible to believe in such thing.

> which are dumb,non sense,unscientific, degrading even if they are
> considered AUTHENTIC like for example:

**Both scientific, intellectual and moral interpretations are subject to change every ten to fifty years and therefore it cannot be a standard in defining rulings.** What is moral to you may not be so moral to others. Islam is giving up your will to God. If there are hadiths mentioned by in Sahih narrations we accept it. In your question, you are not really clear with the kind of others one thousand hadiths you are referring to, please quote one or two hadiths with references what you have read so that others can look at it as it might help others save a lot of time and not waste time in looking for those references.

Answer (score -1):

Wait , you said "you are allowed to drink camel piss"   Who said to you.........I think u aren't aware with the full story , summary is like this - some people came to prophet Mohammed from a different location , they told him that they are having some problem bcz of the environment (may be extreme heat , food poisoning,long travel ,etc) , prophet directed them to a camel owner and told them to add some drops of camel urine with its milk and drink it , and they went there and drink that , and they become healthy after. Now after when they feel relieved  they killed the owner and poped out the eyes of the owner of camel and said that they weren't muslims either.
Now in any other case than this you will never find Muhammad (pbuh) or his companion advising others to drink camel urine, neither any other companian drink that.
Now adding to this, there are tribes in Middle-East who have a culture of drinking camel urine even before Islam came. What I think is that those people who came to Muhammad was from that tribe and were addicted to that camel urine, because they didn't find it disgusting to drink that.

Now regarding " bring me stones inorder to clean my private parts " I think you haven't heard of thing called "Aabdus" , this is method to clean the droplets of urine from your penis. This is performed only in absense of water. Like take "brick" as an example , you can remove the drops of urine by using a piece of "brick " because it absorbs liquid.

Now regarding facial hair removal , you said "women who pluck thier eyebrows will never enter Jannah " this totally wrong or say exaggerated, the original hadith says" its forbidden for women to have tattoes, spacing thier teeth , and plucking facial hair" , nowhere in the hadith it says that they will never enter Jannah or will go to jahhanam definitely.......
There are many things you didn't quote right , and I m really really sorry my english, my grammer isn't that good.